# How to make Ladder plot?

Tags: r, plot

how can you make a ladder plot in R, please.
Here is a data example:

```
d <- data.frame("Subject" = 1:10,
                        "Group" = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 4)),
                        "Gender" = c(rep("male" ,2), rep("female", 6), rep("male", 2)),
                        "Y1" = rnorm(10, 100, 30),
                        "Y2" = rnorm(10, 3000, 1000))
```

in this ladderplot:

- Need to show those with high Y1 also have high Y2
- display the correlations for the "Group" and "Gender" factors
- show the Y axis ticks on the left for Y1 and on the right for Y2
- The two variables (Y1 and Y2) are to be connected for each subject with solid lines for Group 1 and dotted lines for Group 2, red for males and blue for females.

There is something about package plotrix but I cant seem to find details.

Comment: https://github.com/leeper/slopegraph

Answer (score 0):

The ggplot2 library is so flexible, I'd use that, instead of looking for a canned routine.  Here's code that has the basics of the ladder graph.  Look at the existing documentation for things like [secondary axes](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html), and [changing the scales](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#section-scales) of color & linetype.  I'm leaving this so your post feels like it's asking a focused question (and won't be flagged as [a request for a code writing service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348591/how-to-flag-close-as-not-a-code-writing-service)).

The important step below actually comes before the graphing call.  Change your 'wide' format to 'long.

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)

d <- data.frame(
  Subject = 1:10,
  Group   = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 4)),
  Gender  = c(rep("male" ,2), rep("female", 6), rep("male", 2)),
  Y1      = rnorm(10, 100, 30),
  Y2      = rnorm(10, 3000, 1000)
)        

d_long <- d %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key=Time, value=Score, -Subject, -Group, -Gender) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Group = factor(Group)
  )

ggplot(d_long, aes(x=Time, y=Score, group=Subject, linetype=Group, color=Gender)) +
  geom_line()
```

Results

```
> head(d_long)
  Subject Group Gender Time     Score
1       1     1   male   Y1  84.93423
2       2     1   male   Y1 103.94593
3       3     1 female   Y1  97.63249
4       4     1 female   Y1 126.60354
5       5     1 female   Y1 103.50914
6       6     1 female   Y1 109.55890
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much- this is very helpful, but how can you add the 2nd axis then?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you wibeasley for your input! it was greatly helpful. I used however the following code to generate my results.

```
# Melt dataset for plot:
library(reshape)
melted_data<-melt(d, id.vars=c("Subject","Group","Sex"),measure.vars= c("Y1","Y2"))
melted_data$Group<-as.factor(melted_data$Group)


# calcuate R2 per Group and Sex combination
require(plyr)
func <- function(xx)
{  return(data.frame(R2 = round (cor(xx$Y1, xx$Y2),6)))}
CorrDataset<-ddply(d, .(Group,Sex), func)


# plot:
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

p <-ggplot(melted_data, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Subject, linetype=Group, color=Sex)) +
  geom_line(size=1)
#p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ scale(.), name = "Y2"))
p+theme(legend.position="top",
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 2),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 2),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())+
  annotation_custom(tableGrob(CorrDataset,rows = rownames(CorrDataset)),  ymin=4000, ymax=4000)
```

[image]

Please note: For the second Y axis, its commented out in the code above.