# Join paired points within each category in seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've got some data, grouped by category (i.e. "a","b","c" etc), and I'd like to draw lines between each pair of points *within* each category.

Basically, each category has a "before" and "after" value, so I've split it that way with hue. This is the plot now, but eventually I want each "before" and "after" value for a given category to be joined with a line (i.e. a_before joins to a_after, b_before joints to b_after, etc).

```
sns.pointplot (x = ‘category’, y = ‘correlation’, 
    hue = ‘time’, linestyles = ‘’, dodge = .3, data = sample_data)
```

[image: point plot]

I set linestyles to '' because otherwise it joins all the points rather than only the paired points.Is there a way to do this with seaborn?

Thanks!

edit: I'd like it to look something like this:

[image]

(I set linestyles to '' because otherwise it joins all the points rather than only the paired points.)

Comment: Seaborn doesn't know pairty. You need to at least tell it which point pairs to which. Here's something related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417004/how-to-generate-this-weird-plot-what-type-of-plot-is-it-anyway

Comment: Are you trying to create two plots, one connecting all 'before' points, the other one connecting all 'after' points, on the same axes?
Have you tried to run basic `plot` twice?

Comment: @YuliaV Not quite-- I'd like to join each pair of points within the categories (a,b,c etc), rather than joining all the before and afters. I've edited the post where I've just manually drawn in the lines I want to be able to plot. Thanks!!

Comment: I feel it is easier to do it with matplotlib but not sure about `sns.pointplot`

Comment: for each pair, you would need to run something like:
`plt.plot(x=[x_before, x_after], y=[y_before, y_after])`
For more on `plot`, see
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Comment: You would need to post a minimal reproducible snippet to get a more detailed answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib stores the generated points into the `lines` field of the `ax`.
`sns.pointplot()` always generates (possibly empty) confidence intervals which also get stored into the lines. The same positions are also stored in `ax.collections`.

You can loop through `collections[0]` and `collections[1]` to access the exact position of the (dodged) points. Then, you can draw lines between them:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sample_data = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                            'correlation': [0.33, 0.58, 0.51, 0.7, 0.49, 0.72],
                            'time': ['before', 'after', 'before', 'after', 'before', 'after']})
ax = sns.pointplot(x='category', y='correlation', hue='time', palette=['skyblue', 'dodgerblue'],
                   linestyles='', dodge=.3, data=sample_data)for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in zip(ax.collections[0].get_offsets(), ax.collections[1].get_offsets()):
    ax.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], color='black', ls=':', zorder=0)
ax.axhline(0, color='black', ls='--')
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.pointplot connecting different hues]